# Experimental Justification for envelope function approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory

The traditional device picture for describing electron dynamics in conduction bands of semiconductors and heterostructures uses Envelop Function approximation (EFA). The EFA assumes the external perturbation modifying the electron wavefunction in such a way that the wavefunction gets contribution only from the lowest-lying states in the conduction band. As a result, we get a function that is a slowly varying envelope multiplied by a fast varying wavefunction characteristic of the $\Gamma$ point. Once this is done, we have a simpler vacuum Schrodinger equation that allows treating electrons with an effective mass and potential barriers.

I want to ask what are the experimental results that justify this approximation about contribution only from the lowest-lying states. I think a possible case can be to shine light and observe the energy of emitted electrons, if we find that the highest energy electrons came only from around the conduction band minima, this would justify our assumption.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in semiconductors the ground state is a fully occupied valence band (VB) and an empty conduction band (CB). Only at finite temperatures you have filled CB states because of thermal activation, which is also why resistivity decreases with rising temperature in semiconductors (over a certain range). At room temperature $k_BT\approx 25meV$ and typical bandgaps are in the order of 1eV. So the states that are most likely occupied in the CB are those at the CB minimum, and we can ignore higher lying states to lowest order.

For experimental evidence I can give the example of quantized conductance in 1D channels off the top of my hat. This prediction is based on envelope functions treated as the wavefunction in the effective mass Hamiltonian. Their "width" determines how wide the quantized steps in conduction are, i.e. how much the channel width has to be increased to get another conduction channel.

But I guess there might also be evidence from band structure spectroscopy in materials with H-like impurities. With the envelope approximation you can predict their bound-state energy levels. I don't have seen any measurement results on that though, but google probably will give you some publications on that.

EDIT: The term you want to look for is "ARPES" (short for angle resolved photoemission spectroscopy).